# I am getting an IndexError when attempting to make a PostFixEval in Python

Tags: python, postfix-mta, evaluation

So I am working on a PostFix Evaluation code and I cant seem to wrap my head around what is wrong here.

```
def postfixEval(postfixExpr):
    tokenList = postfixExpr.split()
    stack = []
    for token in tokenList:
        if token == '+':
            stack.append(stack.pop() + stack.pop())
        elif token == '-':
            op2 = stack.pop()
            stack.append(stack.pop()-op2)
        elif token == '*':
            stack.append(stack.pop() * stack.pop())
        elif token == '/':
            op2 = stack.pop()
            if op2 != 0:
                stack.append(stack.pop() / op2)
        
    return stack.pop()
```

Here's an example Test Case that is giving me this error:

```
print(postfixEval("1 2 +"))
```

> `IndexError: pop from empty list`

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If the token isn't a +-*/, you need to push it onto the stack.  You're only popping and never pushing.  (Well, given your code, you need to convert the token to a number, and then push it onto the stack.)

Comment: So basically adding another elif that checks if the token is numeric and then appends?

Comment: Yep.  Right now, your stack is empty, and you do nothing but pop non-existent elements off it.   "3 5 +" needs to push the 3 and the 5 before it pops them to add them.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the help!